# Running ML preprocessing job in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker, aws-fargate

My dear people,

I am running some processing jobs in some files stored in S3, I just need regular computing power without GPU. I found I can use both [Sagemaker preprocessing jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-using-amazon-sagemaker-inference-pipelines-and-scikit-learn/) using [Sagemaker SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/); and also can do the exact same task using [Fargate based AWS ECS Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html) using the Python-based [ECS SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.htm). When I compare the procedure it seems like both of them are very similar which is

- Build a docker image
- Push the image to ECR
- Configure Fargate or ECS
- Run the task

Also from the pricing model, it seems really close; so I am wondering why on the same platform there are two services doing a very similar thing. Can anyone explain the motivation behind it and which service to use when if I don't need GPU?